# ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Still Getting Warning even the solution is applied

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, app-store-connect, cocossharp

Hi i am developing an application on c# which is using xamarin forms and cocossharp. Everytime i published on the apple store I'm getting a warning:

```
ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting submissions of new apps that use UIWebView APIs starting from April 2020. See 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview for more information.

After you’ve corrected the issues, you can upload a new binary to App Store Connect.
```

this is not new to me because I am receiving this warning last year but apple already give a deadline.

I found out a solution here which is fixed by xamarin.ios team (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/uiwebview-deprecation-xamarin-forms/)

But I am still getting the warning even I followed that solution I also removed **Xamarin.Auth** which I think also using the UIWebView.

Here are the list of my packages used.

[image]

Comment: check this issue on github: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9823

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Material you have to use Xamarin Forms 4.6 version, it seems you are using 4.5.